# RegEx for capturing words in parentheses

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all, regex-group

This is my regex expression:

```
/(\(-caramel-\)|\(-vanilla-\)|)/
```

With this regex expression, This will only detect the **first** **string** which is `(-caramel-)` only

**How to detect all (-caramel-) and (-vanilla-) in a string?**

This is my example string  :

`(-caramel-) John Cina (-vanilla-)(-caramel-)2019-05-19 07:31:05(-vanilla-)`

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: you spell "vanilla" multiple ways in your example, is that on purpose?

Comment: nopee..sry my false , gunna edit it..

Comment: sry i spelled vanilla wrongly..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we wish to have misspelled words in our search, we might be able to do so using list of chars, bounded from left and right with `()`, maybe similar to:

```
\([carmel-]+\)|\([vanila-]+\)
```

[image]

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gwXZcs/1/)

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/gwXZcs/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Test

```
$re = '/\([carmel-]+\)|\([vanila-]+\)/m';
$str = '(-caramel-) John Cina (-vanilla-)(-caramel-)2019-05-19 07:31:05(-vannila-)';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### Demo

This snippet just shows that if the expression works:

```js
const regex = /\([carmel-]+\)|\([vanila-]+\)/gm;
const str = `(-caramel-) John Cina (-vanilla-)(-caramel-)2019-05-19 07:31:05(-vannila-)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: wow this stackoverflow community is amazing! O_O thank you so much Emma for clarify by editing my sloppy question and you provided answer too!